# How to keep the square brackets in place when I extract data from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization, json.net

All:

We are using NEwtonsoft JSON.NET to serialize some C# POCOs, and we get the following:

```
{

    "RouteID": "123321213312",
    "DriverName": "JohnDoe",
    "Shift": "Night",
     "ItineraryCoordinates": [
        [ 9393, 4443 ],
        [ 8832, 3322 ],
        [ 223, 3432 ],
        [ 223, 3432 ]
    ]           
}
```

In an AJAX jQuery function, I have the following:

```
 alert($.parseJSON(data.d).ItineraryCoordinates);
```

Sadly, the result in the popup alert box is:

```
  9393, 4443 , 8832, 3322, 223, 3432, 223, 3432
```

Could someone please tell me how I can implement the code in such a way that the square brackets are kept in place?

Comment: Stop using alert() ... It calls `toString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to achieve what you require:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
alert(JSON.stringify(data.ItineraryCoordinates));
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0ygee4bt/)

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.stringify(dataArray) it is used keep the brackets